# GetOpts for Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Is there a standard or recommended getopts library for Groovy that will allow me to quickly process long and short command line arguements in Groovy?

groovy foo.groovy --fname=foo.txt --output=foo.html --verbose

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could also simply use Groovy CliBuilder (which internally uses Apache Commons Cli).

You will find a good example of how it works here=> http://www.reverttoconsole.com/blog/codesnippets/groovy-clibuilder-in-practice/

```
def cli = new CliBuilder()
cli.with {
     usage: 'Self'
     h longOpt:'help', 'usage information'
     i longOpt:'input', 'input file', args:1
     o longOpt:'output', 'output file',args:1
     a longOpt:'action', 'action to invoke',args:1
     d longOpt:'directory','process all files of directory', args:1
}
def opt = cli.parse(args)
def action
if( args.length == 0) {
    cli.usage()
    return
}
if( opt.h ) {
    cli.usage()
    return
}
if( opt.i ) {
input = opt.i
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the major strengths of Groovy is interoperability with Java. Therefore, when looking for libraries to use in Groovy, my first instinct is to look for existing Java libraries.

[Args4j](https://args4j.dev.java.net/) is a concise and elegant library for parsing command line options *and* it works perfectly with Groovy classes. I've rewritten parts of the [tutorial](https://args4j.dev.java.net/sample.html) to work with Groovy.

Consider the following Groovy class:

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j.Option;

class Business {

        @Option(name="-name",usage="Sets a name")
        String name

        public void run() {

                println("Business-Logic")
                println("-name: " + name)
        }
}
```

Compile it with:

```
groovyc -classpath .:args4j-2.0.12/args4j-2.0.12.jar Business.groovy
```

and run it with

```
java -cp .:args4j-2.0.12/args4j-2.0.12.jar:/usr/share/java/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-1.6.4.jar -Dmainclass=Business org.kohsuke.args4j.Starter -name sample
```

To get the output

```
Business-Logic
-name: sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I wrote the [Groovy Option Parser](http://code.google.com/p/groovy-option-parser/) to accomplish this task. It's pretty straight forward and has some niceties.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) is another Java library that you could use in Groovy